# submit spark Diagnostics: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

I'm using following command

```
   bin/spark-submit --class com.my.application.XApp 
--master yarn-cluster
 --executor-memory 100m 
--num-executors 50 
/Users/nish1013/proj1/target/x-service-1.0.0-201512141101-assembly.jar
 1000
```

and getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: and I can see on my cluster Yarn the app status as FAILED.

The jar is available at the location. Is there any specific place I need to place this jar when use cluster mode spark submit ?

```
Exception:

Diagnostics: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/Users/nish1013/proj1/target/x-service-1.0.0-201512141101-assembly.jar does not exist
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Comment: Could you post the whole exception? Because I don't know which file is missing. It might be a file that you load in the application, it might be anything ...

Comment: Did you see the log like "INFO Client: Uploading resource file:x-service-1.0.0-201512141101-assembly.jar" in your spark-submit console?

Comment: @ShawnGuo no I don't see such a feedback

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the jar file to the execution nodes by adding it to the "--jar" argument of spark-submit. E.g.

```
bin/spark-submit --class com.my.application.XApp 
--master yarn-cluster
--jars "/Users/nish1013/proj1/target/x-service-1.0.0-201512141101-assembly.jar"
--executor-memory 100m 
--num-executors 50 
/Users/nish1013/proj1/target/x-service-1.0.0-201512141101-assembly.jar 1000
```